# 3.5 .Net Framework Cryptographic Problem

Tags: .net, windows-xp, cryptography, msdn

To crypt and store the password of my client-application in the user-pc I have found this MSDN example (created for other purposes):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397867(VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397867%28VS.90%29.aspx)

For added security I create a new file every time at the startup of the application. Now it seems that sometimes, on some pc (until now only with Windows XP), something goes wrong in the process of creating or reading the crypted file and it becomes necessary to re-enter the password. I don't understand deeply the code of the MSDN example (in particoular the methods "EncryptFile" and "DecryptFile") then I ask you: for your experience, is it possible that this code will generate errors in some client-installations?
Thank you!
Pileggi

Comment: *"To crypt and store the password"* - are you storing a password for another application, or is this your application's password?  If the latter, you should [not be storing the password at all](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html).

Comment: Are you saying you copy&pasted the *example* code without understanding it and it doesn't seem to work all the time?

Comment: To @BlueRaja: thanks for your response. The password is the one that allows the user to acceed to client-application. I have thought to store the password in the user-pc. Why you say it's not right? I dont' need a perfect security: there are other tools to control the user-activities. Have you some suggestions for me?

Comment: @pileggi:  Yes, check the link I posted.  You should never, ever, **ever** store passwords for your own application - store [a hash of the password](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307020) instead.

Comment: @BlueRaja: Ok, Thank you! Naturally I not store the plain password, but a file with the string crypted like explained in the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397867(VS.90).aspx I have thought it were a good cryptation, but if you think HASH MD5 is better I can use that. Do You think that HASH MD5 is a good solution?

Comment: @BlueRaja: I ask this because someone have told me that HASH MD5 is a decryptble algorithm. I'm not an expert, can you tell me something about?

Comment: @pileggi: Please see my coding horror link above.

Comment: @BlueRaja: Yeah, I have seen it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [protected data api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to store this. 1) its way easier to use since its just one call and then save the returned data somewhere 2) It is way way more secure. No matter what you with encrypting the password, you have to store the key somewhere on the system, its not secure.

The protected data api, on the other hand, derives the password from the users log on credentials, so the key material is actually not on the system.